# Kotlin - how to use sort function

Tags: kotlin

Hallo Ladys and Gentleman,

i strugle with a function.
I want convert a given String to a MutableMap.

String:

```
var testString = "hshhfzrt" + "hszrhhtnt"
```

function to use:

```
charMap.toList().sortedByDescending { (_, value) ->
value }.toMap()
```

Final Output should be a Sorted Char in a new String.

Output example(Not related to testString is just example):
`hhh, lll, aaa,`

I hope you can help me.

Thx for reading this and your time.

Comment: The output example does not seem to relate to _testString_, or does it?

Comment: Yes, is just example :D

Comment: Well, the correct it so that it matches, please.

Comment: You cannot expect answers it your question is not properly asked. So again: what is the expected output?

Comment: To help you understand why this is important: What is the significance of the fact, that the output string contains each letter three times? What shall a reader of your question conclude from that – especially since you mention that it is not related to _testString_?

Comment: What? You want to conver a String to a mutable map but the expected is `Sorted Char in a new String`? Those types are not even the same, what do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val testString = "hshhfzrt" + "hszrhhtnt"

val result = testString
  .toList()
  .sorted()
  .groupBy { it }
  .map { it.value.joinToString("") }
  .joinToString(", ")

println(result)   // Output: "f, hhhhhh, n, rr, ss, ttt, zz"
```

Comment: a little variation to this solution with same result: `testString.groupBy { it }.map { it.value.joinToString("") }.sorted().joinToString()`